# MS App Center Build Failed, "fatal: No url found for submodule path 'android/app/src/main/assets' in .gitmodules" Expo React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, github, expo

When I try to build from github repo Android and iOS I see this error: "fatal: No url found for submodule path 'android/app/src/main/assets' in .gitmodules
##[error]Git submodule update failed with exit code: 128"

I've only started using App Center.

I tried building and Android and iOS app, and expected it to work because when i used expo eas build it succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! just needed to expo eject (npx expo prebuid for the local cli)